# create a Spring Bean from Kotlin property

Tags: spring, kotlin

I'm using Kotlin for a Spring application (not Spring Boot), and I would like to create a Bean from a property.

It started out as a function with a separate backing field

```
private val _guessCount = 10

@Bean
open fun guessCount() = _guessCount
```

But then I started looking for a more concise way:

```
@Bean
open val guessCount: Int = 10
```

... which throws an exception

```
Kotlin: This annotation is not applicable to target 'member property with backing field'
```

So I tried it by using the `get` accessor:

```
@get:Bean
open val guessCount: Int = 10
```

... which throws another exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'int' available: expected single matching bean but found 1: getGuessCount
```

This exception makes sense but now I can only solve it in this way:

```
@get:Bean("guessCount")
open val guessCount: Int = 10
```

or

```
open val guessCount: Int = 10
    @Bean("guessCount") get
```

These work but they look kinda ugly. Especially with the string `guessCount`

Does anyone know of a nicer way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered subclassing the `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator`, and setting an instance of it on the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`?  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.html#setBeanNameGenerator-org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanNameGenerator-